# expo ios build failed with Windows

Tags: json, react-native, expo, eas

i am trying to build an app for ios store, but i am having  the issue:

`Build failed: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.`

i am using an expo-managed workflow and a Windows laptop, and it builds perfectly when i am trying to build aab but when i try to build with eas build --platform ios it gives that issuse

this is my eas.josn:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.14.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    },
    "androidapk": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

then this is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "APP_NAME",
    "slug": "APP_SLUG",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.APP_NAME.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "versionCode": 15,
      "package": "com.APP_NAME.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "PROJECT_ID"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

please if anyone has a clue please share